# Remove entries of matrix where both row and column are all zeros

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

For spectral clustering I am building a small similarity matrix like this:

```
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.         0.06750058 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.06750058 0.         0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
```

Due to a bug (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2089), the calculation of the eigenvalues does not work with this matrix, and so I would like to change it to get a square matrix of the following form:

```
[0.         0.06750058]
[0.06750058 0.        ]
```

In other words I want to remove all entries with rows and columns consisting of only zeroes. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter them by `ix_`:

```
 a[np.ix_(a.any(0), a.any(1))]
```

output:

```
[[0.         0.06750058]
 [0.06750058 0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I just realized that the below code only works, if all entries of your array are non-negative. Better use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) then (cf. [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)):

```py
print(a[np.ix_(*a.nonzero())])
```

---

Find all rows and columns with at least one non-zero entry using [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), and construct a proper index array using [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html). You'll get a one-liner for that (where `a` is your NumPy array):

```py
print(a[np.ix_(np.sum(a, axis=1) > 0, np.sum(a, axis=0) > 0)])
```

Output:

```
[[0.         0.06750058]
 [0.06750058 0.        ]]
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
NumPy:       1.19.4
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This will fail if the total sum of a row or column add up to zero.

Comment: @Ehsan I just realized that, yeah. Was already preparing an edit. Thanks for pointing out nonetheless!

Comment: Welcome. You can use `np.abs` to resolve it, but an easier way is what I included in the post below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses `np.isclose` to identify values close to zero; it is not safe to use an equality comparison with floating point numbers.  It then uses `np.all` with an axis argument to identify rows and columns which contain only zeros.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0.06750058, 0.],
                [0., 0., 0.06750058, 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

nonzero_rows = ~np.all(np.isclose(arr, 0), axis=1)
nonzero_cols = ~np.all(np.isclose(arr, 0), axis=0)
reduced_arr = arr[nonzero_rows, :]
reduced_arr = reduced_arr[:, nonzero_cols]

print(reduced_arr)
# [[0.         0.06750058]
#  [0.06750058 0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a one liner, but you can try `np.where` with `np.ix_`:

```
x,y = np.where(arr)
arr[np.ix_(sorted(x), sorted(y))]
```